# Recovering a corrupted text file from a USB drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, data-recovery

I've got two quite important .txt files on a thumb drive that seem to have become corrupted. One has been interlaced with parts of another document, and the original content reduced to gibberish symbols. The other is all gibberish symbols, like this:

> ´”MOƒ@†ï&þ²WÛz0Æ”ö õ¨M¬ñ¼.CÙÈ~dgûõïJKª¡¥Z½À2ïûÌ3ƒÑJ—Ñ<*kRÖOz,#m¦Ì,e¯ÓÇø–E„ÉDi
>   ¤l ÈFÃË‹Átí #ª6˜²"wÇ9Ê´ÀÄ:0t’[¯E [?ãNÈ1~ÝëÝpiM
>   âPi°áàr1/C4^ÑãšÄC‰,º¯_¬¼R&œ+•HùÂdß\â­CB•›w°P¯ƒñV‡êä°Á¶î™¢ñ*ƒh"|xš0øÒúŒgVÎ5õ—iá´y®$4õ•šóV"e®Ë¤9ÑB™ÿAëðï)jÝíßT(Æy’>vwãªé¤¶Ø«ívƒ(¤SL¾þ‚qWè¸UîDXÂûË¿Qì‰w‚ä4Sñ^Â   ‰ÿ0ŒFº"Ð¼ß\ûgsldŽYÒdL¼uHûÃÿ¢íÝ‚¨ªc9>(hVDÛˆ5Ž´{Îîªí–AÖâÍ7Ûtø 
>   ÿÿ PK     ! ‘·ó   N   _rels/.rels ¢(

I don't have backups. Silly, but I use this drive to hold files that I work on across different machines, which makes backups awkward as the content is always changing. I really have no idea how they got this way - other material on the drive seems fine, and Windows detects no errors when you plug it in.

I can't use Windows "Previous Versions" because they're on a USB drive.

I've tried using Word's built in file recovery tool, to no avail.

I've tried several free file recovery apps but they seem focused on retrieving deleted data, and this seems to be corrupted, not deleted.

It doesn't seem to be file encoding either - I've tried fiddling around with that, and they were written in notepad ++ in any case, which has decent encoding support.

Anything else I can try? Any applications that can actually try and rebuild corrupted files? Or am I just going to have to rewrite them?

Answer (score 1):

"Or am I just going to have to rewrite them?" DING DING DING here's your answer (unfortunately).

The computer can't reconstruct data from nothing. "Hello computer, figure out what I want to say and type it for me will ya"?  We're not there yet. :)

You've exhausted all your avenues; corruption is one of the reasons why backups exist.  Shed a tear, suck it up, and start (re)typing.

Comment: Rats. I was hoping it might be a garbled file end or something, causing the binary to be read out of line.